# How can I change picturebox image at runtime 

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface

I want to change the `pictureBox` background image at the mousemove event of the contextmenu strip but whereas my image is residing in the application Images folder, I'm getting error when running the code

```
private void hOMEToolStripMenuItem_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("Images/LIFELINE.jpg");
}
```

The error is `file not found exception`.

Images is a folder residing in the application folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Images is the folder or directory residing in the application folder please help me i have

Just because it's in the application folder doesn't mean your application is going to find it. The path you are specifying is *relative*, not absolute. The *relative* part is relative to the *working directory* of your application.

I would check that first.

Comment: so how would i be able to specify the path of the folder since i m working on this project on too many computers so i cant leave the folder on local drive

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio, in which case you want to specify the `Working Directory` in Project Options - see http://www.sedodream.com/content/binary/042908_0515_HowtodebugM3.png

Answer (score 1):

This is how it is done in VB6:

```
Image.FromFile(Application.StartuPath & "Directory/ImageFile.jpg")
```

just try it on yours. Good luck